Are questions that involve translating between Chinese and another non-English language on-topic?
This post has been bumped to the front page: Translations of 主编 and 总编 in French.
Question: Are questions that involve translating between Chinese and another non-English language on-topic?
This shouldn't be discussed in the comments of such questions, but here on meta.
We've established that English and Chinese are fine.  But is French?  And what about Japanese, Swahili, Urdu, or Klingon?   And if certain languages are okay and others are not, which ones?  There seems a reasonable line of thought that this makes the question inherently half off-topic.
Perhaps it's worth investigating what other sites do.

I think this kind of question can be separated into two part:

What is the difference between the two words?
Find a translation in some language for each of the word.

The first part is on topic, the second part is not.
The poster should be asked to give the explanations of the two words to someone who is familiar with or native in the target language to find the translations. This particular question may also require experience in certain community. (Being a native Chinese but not in the editing world, I do not know the difference between 主编 and 总编.)
This community can help with giving a detailed explanation of words, and their differences. But not the translating part.
